# How to Ignore a property from being serialized using BinaryFormatter?

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter

```
[Serializable]
class DOThis
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (_name == "Hi")
                return "Hey Hi";
            else
                return "Sorry I dont know you";
        }
    }
}
```

I have the above class to be serialized using BinaryFormatter. Below is the serialization code,

```
DOThis obj = new DOThis();
obj.Name = "Ho";
BinaryFormatter bfm = new BinaryFormatter();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
bfm.Serialize(ms, obj);
```

Here how to ignore the property 'Value' from being serialized and also in deserialize, as I can always retrieve 'Value' property using 'Name' property?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but have you considered protobuf? I've noticed that protobuf is *way* faster than BinaryFormatter in my perf tests.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to make any changes to your code: `BinaryFormatter` only serializes fields, not properties, so it won't serialize `Value`.

Here's a hex dump of the resulting `MemoryStream` which shows that only "_name" and "Ho" are serialized:

```
00 01 00 00 00 FF FF FF  FF 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  .....ÿÿÿÿ.......
00 0C 02 00 00 00 3B 44  65 6D 6F 2C 20 56 65 72  ......;Demo, Ver
73 69 6F 6E 3D 31 2E 30  2E 30 2E 30 2C 20 43 75  sion=1.0.0.0, Cu
6C 74 75 72 65 3D 6E 65  75 74 72 61 6C 2C 20 50  lture=neutral, P
75 62 6C 69 63 4B 65 79  54 6F 6B 65 6E 3D 6E 75  ublicKeyToken=nu
6C 6C 05 01 00 00 00 0B  44 65 6D 6F 2E 44 4F 54  ll......Demo.DOT
68 69 73 01 00 00 00 05  5F 6E 61 6D 65 01 02 00  his....._name...
00 00 06 03 00 00 00 02  48 6F 0B                 ........Ho.
```

Answer (score -2):

Look at the [`NonSerializedAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx).

```
[Serializable]
class DOThis
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    [NonSerialized()]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (_name == "Hi")
                return "Hey Hi";
            else
                return "Sorry I dont know you";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. `NonSerialized` can only be placed on fields, not on properties. The correct answer is that `BinaryFormatter` *already* ignores `Value`; it only serializes fields.