# How to exclude an attribute when serializing C#-object

Tags: c#, serialization

How can I prevent an attribute from being serialized? I have an abstract class and the class is marked with [Serializable]. But I don't want the attribute Checksum to be included in the serialization. How do I do that?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace test
{

    [DataContract]
    [Serializable]
    public abstract class Baseclass
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The product id.
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember(Name = "productId")]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The calculated checksum for this object. 
        /// It is calculated using SHA1.
        /// For more information about SHA-1, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember(Name = "checksum")]
        public long Checksum
        {
            get
            {
                long tempHash = 0;
                try
                {
                    this.temp = 0;
                    var seraializer = new BinaryFormatter();
                    var sha1 = new SHA1Managed();
                    byte[] buffer;

                    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        seraializer.Serialize(memoryStream, this);
                        buffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    }
                    var bArrayHash = sha1.ComputeHash(buffer);
                    tempHash = Math.Abs(BitConverter.ToInt64(bArrayHash, 0));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
                return tempHash;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried the following code from MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx) but when I try to apply it to my code, the complier says that it is not valid on this declaration type, and that it is only valid on 'field' declarations.

```
// A test object that needs to be serialized.
[Serializable()]        
public class TestSimpleObject  {

    public int member1;
    public string member2;
    public string member3;
    public double member4;

    // A field that is not serialized.
    [NonSerialized()] public string member5; 

    public TestSimpleObject() {

        member1 = 11;
        member2 = "hello";
        member3 = "hello";
        member4 = 3.14159265;
        member5 = "hello world!";
    }


    public void Print() {

        Console.WriteLine("member1 = '{0}'", member1);
        Console.WriteLine("member2 = '{0}'", member2);
        Console.WriteLine("member3 = '{0}'", member3);
        Console.WriteLine("member4 = '{0}'", member4);
        Console.WriteLine("member5 = '{0}'", member5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `[IgnoreDataMember]` attribute on the member you want to ignore.

Comment: It's not going to work since BinaryFormatter serialize fields (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27286034/how-to-ignore-a-property-from-being-serialized-using-binaryformatter).

Answer (score 0):

You can decorate your property with `[XmlIgnore()]` or `[JsonIgnore]` if you are converting that class to a JSON object, depending on the serializer you're using

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to work since BinaryFormatter serialize fields, see [How to Ignore a property from being serialized using BinaryFormatter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27286034/how-to-ignore-a-property-from-being-serialized-using-binaryformatter).

So I think that the solution is to redesign my code.